# How to organize attendance system code (using $_POST instead of $_GET for dynamic forms)?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, code-organization

I'm currently developing an attendance system for my high school.  Right now, my method for submitting data is relatively messy as I'm using the $_GET method.  I'm also executing tons of SQL queries.  I was wondering if I could receive some assistance on simplifying the code.

This form is generated by fetching the student ID, class ID.  If attendance was taken, it fetches the status (Absent, Present, Tardy) or if they are excused by the administrator it's marked "Excused Absense"

This is all being processed through $_GET.  Here's the loop it's running through. Please bear with me, it's not pretty:

The reason I'm using $_GET instead of $_POST is because I do not know how to loop dynamic information in a form and process it.  Any tips?  Sorry if I'm not completely clear: I'm really just trying to find a way to simplify this and not rely so heavily on $_GET (which is a huge security risk, but also sloppy)

Thanks!

Comment: Dates.. I would suggest using UNIX timestamps. This way you have more flexibility when selecting "3 day old" records. 

Also, $_POST in php can be accessed the same way $_GET can. An array is an array..

Comment: Just so you know, `$_GET` is no more or less of a security risk than `$_POST`, both can be altered at will by someone wanting to break your application. But the reason to use `$_POST` is twofold: (1) (Well-behaved!) search engines will never send your webserver a `POST` request, whereas they will send `GET` if they find a parametrised URL (this can break the occasional unwitting site that learns it the hard way). (2) Browsers have a hard limit as to how much information they can submit via `GET` alone, which is a fairly pitiful amount, while `POST` allows considerably more data to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $_POST is used exactly like $_GET, just need to change the input form to use post rather than get.

For the SQL, use JOINs to get to the data in the other tables, since that's essentially what you're doing anyway, you're just doing it manually, SELECT only what you need, and use LIMIT 1 where you expect a unique return.

Oh, by the way, why reinvent the wheel (unless it's for a class project or something), check out [Moodle](http://moodle.org/), there's attendance modules and stuff for it, and it has quite a few nice features.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I looked into Moodle, and the main problem is that my school has a very unique approach to assessments, so I'd end up rewriting it anyway.

How about for sending the form data without using hidden input fields? Right now it's using hidden input fields, and then the while loop.

Comment: Well, that's why Moodle is open source, and your school might not have that much of a unique approach, someone might have made something similar that could be modified.  As for hidden input fields, they are a perfectly valid method of getting info that doesn't need to be changed by the end user into the script that processes it, such as the student id, class id, etc. (and also a valid method of catching bots, as they will often fill in empty hidden fields that look like they need to be filled, which is called a honeypot field).  They work with $_POST and $_GET in the same manner.

Comment: Okay great, I thought maybe I might have been doing it the hard way.  Any idea why sometimes duplicate entries get put into the database? It's strange because I have it checking the mysql_num_rows before inserting data, so it should update if it exists. The relevant lines are towards the bottom of the second script with the $count variables. 

 It seems teachers are somehow submitting data multiple times even though the script shouldn't be inserting new fields, but just update the existing ones.

Comment: Not sure, I guess it's possible they could refresh the page in the middle of processing and have it insert again.  My suggestion would be to modify the table to make sure that classid and date must be unique on studentid with a unique index including the columns, which will make it drop any attempted inserts if classid, studentid, and date have already been used together.  Might require some slight script changes, because it might die on attempting to insert.